# Dojo: How can I update the constraints on a dojo.dnd.boxConstrainedMoveable?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am using a dojo.dnd.boxConstrainedMoveable within an image cropping widget to allow the user to select a sub-region of the original image. Part of this widget allows the user to resize the image. When this happens, I recalculate the box constraints for the dnd.boxConstrainedMoveable.

Below is my code that attempts to update the constraintBox, but doesn't work. Is there another method to have the widget recalculate its constraints based on a new constraintBox, as it calculates the constraints when its instantiated?

```
    # var dnd = reference to the boxConstrainedMoveable itself
    var mb = dojo.marginBox(cropImage);
    var constraintBox = {t: (mb.h - viewportHeight) * -1,
                         l: (mb.w - viewportWidth) * -1,
                         w: mb.w,
                         h: mb.h};
    this.dnd.constraintBox = constraintBox; # overwrites, but then is reset to original when moved
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `constrainedMoveable` instead of `boxConstrainedMoveable`.
The difference is using a predefined box or a dynamic box.
[constrainedMoveable](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/dnd.html#constrainedmoveable)